# For the verb 'focus' why is the gerund form 'focusing' with a single S, instead of 'focussing' with a double S?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, doubled-consonants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Focussed” or “focused”? The double consonant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-the-double-consonant)

The rule that I learned was that when you have a short vowel in the last syllable, you double the last consonant before adding the ending.  Thus "cut" becomes "cutting",  or "beget" becomes "begetting".

According to this rule, "focus" should become "focussing".  But the spell checker in my browser wants me to change that to "focusing".   This bothers me because I would think that would be pronounced something more like fo-kyoo-sing.

I looked this up, and apparently the Brits follow the rule, but Americans don't.  Any idea why?  And what is the rule, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The American rule is that the final consonant is doubled only if the verb is stressed on that syllable and it is a short vowel.

Comment: So why isn't it "bussing" instead of "busing" when referring to school transportation? And I've always spelled _focussing_ with a double S. Even Americans vary.

Comment: @JohnLawler As far as I can tell, *busing* in an irregular. I spell it *focussing*, too, but it is because I am old; I predate mechanical spellcheckers, which enforce a ridiculous ideal of US-vs-UK-ness everywhere.  Bothers me.  Makes people think there is only One True Way to spell a word.

Comment: Ugh. Spellcheckers.

Comment: Interesting, and I don't doubt you; but is there some authority for this?

Comment: @TimLymington If you are addressing me, the current “American rule” of only doubling the final consonant in applicable inflections of verbs stressed on their last syllable is easy to come by. However, it is rather new, and not followed by all. You can do ngrams on the shifting frequencies in the two corpora by time; it is uneven. I myself still always spell things like *cancelled, programmed, signalled, transferred, levelled* that way, because they look “righter” to me. It might be related to length, silly though that sounds, insofar as *dialled, fuelled* can sometimes give me momentary pause.

Comment: "The American rule" where do we find **that**?

Comment: @Kris You ***are*** kidding me, right? Where do you “find” it? You ***find*** it every single possible place you can even begin to start to pretend to look, like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences), [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/british-and-american-spelling), [here](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/british-american-spelling.html), and [here](http://www.englishclub.com/writing/spelling_american-english.htm). So tell me, where was it that ***you*** looked yet somehow managed to miss this obvious thing? I’ll put it on my blacklist.

Comment: @TimLymington I am not sure that “authority” ever quite applies in a situation like this, but
 Oxford is in my list of refs I gave immediately above.

Comment: (replicating comment posted as edit to answer by "anonymous user") Both the British and the American spelling rule is the same for doubling consonants before a suffix with a vowel. If the last consonant has a short stressed vowel then the consonant doubles (swim, swimming, fit, fitting). If the word has more than one syllable and the stress doesn't fall on the last syllable, then the consonant doesn't double. The exception to this is that words ending in 'l' or 'p' in British English do double even in a multisyllable vowel, but they don't in American English...

Comment: Focus is pronounced more ['fou-cas] rather than [foc-'yus] with the 'o' being long and the u is what's called a 'turned v' which is an unstressed sound. The stress is on the first syllable not the last therefore the 's' doesn't double. focus - focusing - focused.

Comment: This rule has exceptions even in America, such as *eavesdropped, kidnapped, formatted,  programmed.* Alex B lists some of them in his answer to the linked question.