# Relic as a verb: why the spelling relicing, reliced?

Tags: etymology, verbs, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, neologisms

I just discovered the verb *relic*, meaning “to make something look worn” and used as far as I can tell only about guitars. (Examples: [1](http://www.stevesguitarsite.com/Relic%20Part%201.html) [2](http://www.guitarrelicing.com/) [3](http://www.tdpri.com/resources/how-to-relic-your-guitar/) …) I was surprised to see that its participles are pretty consistently spelled *relicing* and *reliced*, not **relicking* and **relicked* like other verbs ending in -ic (mimic → mimicking, traffic → trafficking, etc.). No matter what [general rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107157/why-is-k-added-to-panic-when-suffixes-added-as-in-panicky/107179#107179) might tell us, for this particular verb, it is clear that [putting hair pests back onto a guitar is a thing](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22guitar+relicing%22&ie=utf-8) (hundreds of independent hits) whereas [applying one's tongue again isn't](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22guitar+relicking%22&ie=utf-8) (only 7 hits, all of them using *relicing* as well).

Are *relicing* and *reliced* consistently pronounced re-lick-ing/'d as the formation would suggest and not re-lice-ing/'d as the spelling would suggest?

**How did this spelling come about?** Did the verb forms spring from a specific source or did they evolve “naturally”?

Are there other recent verb formations (I believe the verbing of *relic* dates from the electric guitar era) that are spelled this way, or is this an isolated case?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19969/discussion-on-question-by-gilles-relic-as-a-verb-why-the-spelling-relicing-rel).

Comment: I have seen "relicing" regarding guitars also mean "destroy them". I think it might be a sarcastic comment, though.

Comment: In *OED*, we find that the word *relicked* is the past tense of *relick*, meaning "to lick again".  And no listing of *reliced* at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the explanation for your finding that *relicing* is used much more than *relicking,* so here is a partial answer to your other question:

> Are there other recent verb formations (I believe the verbing of relic dates from the electric guitar era) that are spelled this way, or is this an isolated case?

The use of <cing> pronounced /kıŋ/ in "relicing" is not a completely isolated case.

- **arcing.** This spelling pattern also shows up in the word "arcing", the *-ing*-form of the verb *arc.* The Oxford English Dictionary indicates that *arc* has been used as a verb at least since 1893.
- **syncing.** As noted in the answers to the related question ["Synced" or "synched"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/681/synced-or-synched), the verb *sync* also has <ced> and <cing> spellings. It has a variant spelling *synch.*
- **talcing.** The only spelling given by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/talc#talc). [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/talc) lists *talcking* and *talcked* alongside *talcing* and *talced,* but the *-ck-* forms for this verb are uncommon enough to not show up on the Google NGram Viewer, and 
  *[Garner's Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=l2LmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA889&dq="talcking")* specifically says "**talc** [...] anomalously makes *talced* and *talcing,* not **talcked* and **talcking.*"
  The OED's first citation for the verb *talc* is from 1888, and provides an example of the *-ced* spelling: "*Engineer* LXVI. 334   A glass plate is first cleaned, talced, and collodionized."

Comment: Interesting. It does seem that there is a trend of moving from -cking to -cing, with “arc(k)ing” being from the transition period and “syncing” and “relicing” being from after the transition period.

Answer (score 9):

## The Rule:

### Change final *-c* to *-ck-* before certain inflections

As explained in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/107179/2085), the OED says regarding the letter *c* that:

> Hence, in modern English, C has
>
> - (1) the ‘hard’ sound `[k]` before *a*, *o*,
>     *u*, before a consonant (except *h*), and when final, as in
>     *cab*, *cot*, *cut*, *claw*, *crow*, *acme*,
>     *cycle*, *sac*, *tic*, *epic*;
> - (2) before *e*, *i*, *y*, it has the ‘soft’ sound
>     `[s]`.  In all words from Old English or Old French, final
>     *c* is avoided: the `[k]` sound being written *k* or
>     *ck*, as in *beak*, *meek*, *oak*, *book*,
>     *bark*, *balk*, *bank*, *pack*, *peck*,
>     *pick*, *rock*.  This is probably due to the claims of
>     derivatives like *meeker*, *oaken*, *barking*, *rocky*,
>     where *c* could not be used.  Final *c* however is written in
>     modern words from Latin, Greek, or other languages, and (of late) in the
>     ending *‑ic*, as in *sac*, *tic*, *epic*,
>     *critic*, *music*, *picnic*.  **In the rare cases in which
>     this *c* is followed in inflexion by *e* or *i*, it is
>     necessary to change it to *ck*, as in *physicking*,
>     *mimicking*, *frolicking*, *trafficker*, *picnicker*.**
>      When the `[s]` sound is final, it must be written
>     *‑ce*, as in *trace*, *ice*, *thrice*, and this final
>     *e* must be retained in composition before *a*, *o*,
>     *u*, as in *trace-able*, *peace-able*.

These “sound and spelling” rules for inflections and derivations of words ending in *‑c* and in *‑ce* are real rules that apply generally to all such forms. Just as we must write *peaceable* not **peacable*, so too must we write *relicking* not **relicing* — at least when we don’t mean to relouse someone. :)

So this rule gives us words like *mosaicked, colicky, havocker,
picnicky, plasticky, panicking, picnicking, panicky, magicked, colicking,
picnicked, bivouacking, colicked, mimicked, frolicked, picnicker,
demosaicked, garlicky, mimicker, havocking, bivouacked, demosaicker,
havocked, panicked, mimicking, frolicking, demosaicking.*

However, not everyone is particularly solid on the rule that
words ending in *‑c* must first take an extra *‑k‑* before adding
*‑ed*, *‑y*, or *‑ing*  to them.  In today’s world of self-publishing
that never goes through a proper editorial process, nor often enough
even a proper proofread, countless erroneous spellings crop up, such
as **mosaiced* for *mosaicked*.  And although the OED does indeed give published citations for both spellings, it does not actually sanction the one without the *‑k‑* as an admissible alternate: it just documents that people have sometimes spelled it without the *‑k‑* that the OED says is obligatory in such cases.

This is what has happened with *relicky, relicked, relicking*: people
who have never learned the actual rule are making spelling mistakes
that never get corrected to their proper spelling.

---

## In Publication

However, in actual **curated works**,
such spelling errors are far less common, especially in older works where typesetting was dear and corrections dearer.  When the barrier to entry is high, so too the standards. But when there is no barrier to entry and no proofreader worthy of the name, mistakes are made.

Here, though, are curated examples where mistakes were **not** made.

### Published Citations for *Relicky*

Published examples of *relicky* aren’t all that common, but neither
are the especially hard to find.

From [*Forest and Stream*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ejQevDPMUIYC&pg=PA968&dq=%22relicky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O3GhVPqbKIqkyQSY34KoAw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBg):

> I had a stock saddle and a dealer in more or less “**relicky**” relics
>   supplied me with a pair of canvas saddle bags that once were the property
>   of Uncle Sam.

From [*Boys' Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qr5Bxa2MQ0kC&pg=PA41&dq=%22relicky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O3GhVPqbKIqkyQSY34KoAw&ved=0CGQQ6AEwDA):

> They had said the old tug was **relicky**, a has-been.

And again from the next month of [*Boys' Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=V0Q0RfxXAO4C&pg=PA4&dq=%22relicky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O3GhVPqbKIqkyQSY34KoAw&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBw):

> There’s nothing **relicky** about my boilers and engines! They can pull with the best of ’em.

Or here from [*The New Yorker*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7xAnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22relicky%22&dq=%22relicky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O3GhVPqbKIqkyQSY34KoAw&ved=0CGgQ6AEwDQ):

> Did I mention that now when I tell cab-drivers my right age they say,
>   ‘God bless you’? It gives you a very **relicky** feeling. You’re supposed to
>   have profound wisdom and a philosophy of life.

### Published Citations for *Relicked*

One can find published examples of the proper spelling *relicked*,
such as mention of *relicked bones* from [*Britannia Antiquissima, Or, A Key to the Philology of History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ze4tqo70SUgC&pg=PA172&dq=%22relicked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=22KhVMuaM4KdyASvnYCgAw&ved=0CHIQ6AEwDw):

> . . . according to the gorgeous fertility of the imaginations of the
>   exorcists, and averring that the apis, ibis, serpents, goats, **relicked**
>   bones, pictures, or garments of this or that animal or being . . .

Here is a use of *relicked* using the second sort of *-ed* suffix,
the one used to make adjectives from nouns, not the one to make
past-tense forms from verbs.  It’s from [*A Suit of Four*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ta9AAQAAIAAJ&q=%22relicked%22&dq=%22relicked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=22KhVMuaM4KdyASvnYCgAw&ved=0CNoBEOgBMCM) by Arnold
Leslie Lazarus:

> Twenty gravel miles yet by map — and rode that **relicked** land out keen edged
>   as its air ...

A verbal use of *relicked* is found — wholly unsurprisingly — in [*Relics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RIsIAQAAMAAJ&q=%22relicked%22&dq=%22relicked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=22KhVMuaM4KdyASvnYCgAw&ved=0CPwBEOgBMCs):

> As he and his wife **relicked** throughout Arkansas and Missouri while on
>   vacation they stopped every time they saw an old wagon and tried to dicker
>   with the owner for whatever good parts the wagon contained.

The word *relicked* appears from time to time in verse, such as
in the [*Collected Poems* of William Hull](https://books.google.com/books?id=FHxXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22relicked%22&dq=%22relicked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=22KhVMuaM4KdyASvnYCgAw&ved=0CKQBEOgBMBg):

> no monstrance holds same love in **relicked** gold:
>   love does not hold its stay: let gold be sound,
>   it will descend to brass, to lead through old
>   perverting alchemist, thin-lipped and bold.

Other examples in verse are easy to find.

### Published Citations for *Relicking*

As for *relicking* as a participle or gerund, many published examples exist.

In [*The Sebago Lakes Region: A Brief History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OOwF1nCTZsYC&pg=PA15&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22relicking%22&f=false), author Red Allen notes that:

> “**Relicking**” even became a verb, meaning to search for Indian relics.

That was published in 2013, but it is hardly a new use, for way back in 1941
the National Recreation Association published a chapter in their
[*Recreation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U3gVAAAAIAAJ&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) with the title:

> Have You Tried “**Relicking**”?

Other published citations for the spelling *relicking* that mean the antique version not the licking version include
[[1]](https://books.google.com/books?id=sIwIAQAAMAAJ&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CLQBEOgBMBs),
[[2]](https://books.google.com/books?id=KvByAAAAMAAJ&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CLgBEOgBMBw),
[[3]](https://books.google.com/books?id=g1VzAAAAMAAJ&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CLwBEOgBMB0),
[[4]](https://books.google.com/books?id=p4srAQAAIAAJ&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CMABEOgBMB4),
[[5]](https://books.google.com/books?id=hbtPAQAAIAAJ&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CMQBEOgBMB8),
[[6]](https://books.google.com/books?id=nccaKEuLMAoC&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CNEBEOgBMCI),
and
[[7]](https://books.google.com/books?id=K0k7AQAAIAAJ&q=%22relicking%22&dq=%22relicking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KmShVN_xN8ugyAS1voCYAw&ved=0CPABEOgBMCg).

#### But what about guitars?

Lest one mistakenly think that these many instances of *relicking* are somehow a different word from the
one used in the context of making something like a guitar look like a
relic, from 2012 we have this clear example from Dave Hunter’s [The Fender Telecaster: The Life and Times of the Electric Guitar That Changed the World](https://books.google.com/books?id=sUn0AwAAQBAJ&dq=%22relicking%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s):

> In addition to natural distress of the sort that would make the Fender
>   Custom Shop’s **relicking** team drool with envy, Nancy displays Buchanan’s
>   name crudely etched into its back at the bass-side upper bout, and three
>   characteristic friction marks behind the bridge where screwdrivers of old
>   were used to adjust the brass saddles.

There can be no question that that citation uses the sense of *relicking*
meaning “antiquing” something, not the one meaning to give something a
new lick.  And it is itself no relic, either, having seen publication
in 2012.

---

## Miriads of Mispelled Occurances [*sic*]

You can always find virtually infinite misspellings.  That doesn’t make them right.  Consider for example:

- [41,100,000 instances of the misspelling *seperate*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22seperate%22)
- [23,000,000 instances of the misspelling *occured*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22occured%22)
- [8,540,000 instances of the misspelling *seperated*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22seperated%22)
- [7,460,000 instances of the misspelling *seperately*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22seperately%22)
- [6,320,000 instances of the misspelling *occurence*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22occurence%22)
- [687,000 instances of the misspelling *occurance*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22occurance%22)
- [441,000 instances of the misspelling *mispelled*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mispelled%22)
- [437,000 instances of the misspelling *occurances*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22occurances%22)
- [357,000 instances of the misspelling *mispelling*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mispelling%22)
- [10,400 instances of the misspelling *miriads*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22miriads%22)

Those are much commoner words than the *‑ck‑* words, but nonetheless that’s a lot of them to be considered wrong. Millions and millions.  Surely **more than *forty million* instances** of people spelling *sep**a**rate* as *sep**e**rate* must finally be enough to make the second one count as correct, right?

No. That’s exactly the wrong conclusion.  The right conclusion is that a lot of people don’t know how to spell. Don’t let anyone tell you that those are right, because they aren’t.  It doesn’t matter how many cases you can find of people making spelling mistakes.

Now let us consider the many errors people make in spelling *‑ck‑* words:

- [241,000 instances of the misspelling *mimicing*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mimicing%22)
- [240,000 instances of the misspelling *picnicing*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22picnicing%22)
- [207,000 instances of the misspelling *trafficed*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22trafficed%22)
- [112,000 instanced of the misspelling *frolicing*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22frolicing%22)
- [84,600 instances of the misspelling *magiced*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22magiced%22)
- [54,300 instances of the misspelling *mimiced*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mimiced%22)
- [50,000 instances of the misspelling *trafficer*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22trafficer%22)

These are smaller in magnitude, but they are all the same class of error.  And error they remain, for the second set is no more correct than the first set.

There is no number of incorrect answers that add up to a right answer.

---

## Summary

Curated works show all three of *relicky, relicked, relicking* spelled as
perfect analogues of *picnicky, picnicked, picnicking*.

Non-curated works
like random Internet jabber, self-published works, and periodicals not
especially well-known for accuracy in English orthography often contain
errors in spelling.

At times these misspellings can come to be repeated in a particular
field so often that readers may become inured to the error and therefore no longer able to judge right from wrong.  A good example of this is how
often the erroneous *demosaiced image* is used in Internet jabber instead of the correctly spelled
*demosaicked image*.

This is what has occurred here with *relicky, relicked, relicking*. People who didn’t understand the “*‑c* > *‑ck‑*” rule (and had no competent proofreader) typed spelling errors, and some other people got used to seeing these errors.

There can be no answer to “why” the people who made that error did so.  We might speculate about cognitive interference with *re-licing* being less strong than that of *re-licking*, but in the end, no one can say.  It’s like *recreation* meaning both a new creation and also a pleasant diversion: some words have more than one completely different meaning.

Comment: Does OED give _musicing_ (or indeed _relicing_)?

Comment: This is a nice and impressively documented answer, but I'm afraid it misses the point. Only the last two paragraphs are relevant, and they are lacking references. Whence do you conclude that guitar relicers, who [uniformly eschew a K](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22guitar+relicker%22) (0 hits for `"guitar relicker"`), are “unable to judge right from wrong”?

Comment: @Gilles I don’t see how they aren’t relevant: it’s the same word. Furthermore, the final *Fender Telecaster* reference is precisely what you are looking for as far as context goes, is it not? Do you really want me to pull out comparative statistics on misspellings of commonly misspelled words in Internet jabber like Facebook and Twitter and cell phone txtsp3k? How would that help anything? I don’t see how being an expert on relicking guitars should make one an authority on English spelling.

Comment: If the K-less spelling is purely a sign of ignorance, why does it constitute an overwhelming majority of the usage, and not about half (which is what it would be if each randomly decided to include a K or not)? The K-less spelling is shorter, granted, but does our experience with other words justify this explanation? How much of an outlier is *guitar relicing* in terms of commonality of the “wrong” spelling? Does it come from a single origin (which would explain the uniformity of the spelling)?

Comment: Just because there are exactly two possibilities regarding whether a letter is present or absent does not imply that we should expect to find these in equal distribution: tomorrow you shall either be alive or dead, but there is not a 50% chance of each. [The 242,000 Google results for *picnicing*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22picnicing%22) seem to prove that random Internet jabberers don’t have a firm command of English spelling when it comes to this rule. That doesn’t mean they are right.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, for the verb *magic* the OED does not say it is irregular, and indeed they provide only *‑ck‑* inflections in its citations. FOR EXAMPLE: “1909 L. M. Montgomery *Anne of Avonlea* xxiv. 282, ― I actually have a half-guilty feeling as if I had **‘magicked’** it [sc. a storm] up.” and “1973 D. Francis *Slay-Ride* iv. 56 ― He **magicked** some huge open sandwiches on about a foot of French loaf.” You’d have to ask them to be sure, but their rule given under *C* suggests to me that they would consider your proposed **magicing* an error since it violates their established rule.

Comment: The word I was querying was _musicing_. (If you've got the same bug I'm trying to get fight off, it makes reading rather difficult).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I could find no citations with *musicing*, at least in the normal place to look for these things.

Comment: Thank you. // I'm not so descriptivist that I accept just any change as being for the good or even not worth standing against (as you well know from the neologisms / productiveness debate). And I think the 'add a _k_' recommendation comes as close to a rule as we get in English. We're probably all at different places along the prescriptivist - descriptivist continuum. Perhaps different places for different usages.