# What's the rule for doubling 't' in verbs like 'getting' vs. 'targeting'

Tags: doubled-consonants

In verbs that end with "et", what is the rule for doubling the final consonant for present participle?

Examples where doubling is used:

- getting
- typesetting
- forgetting

Examples where a single 't' is written:

- targeting
- marketing
- pocketing

Comment: See also [“Focussed” or “focused”? Rules for doubling the last consonant when adding -ed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-rules-for-doubling-the-last-consonant-when-adding-ed) for discussion of examples like "typesetting" where even though the syllable directly before *-ing* does not have the primary stress of the word, it can be considered to have some kind of minor stress, or can be viewed as the final element of a compound word.

Comment: Another related question: [Is “targetted” a standard British English spelling?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205815)