# Are "worshiping" and "worshipping" interchangeable?

Tags: verbs, orthography, participles, conjugation, doubled-consonants

Every online source seems to agree with the preconceived notion I had that the correct usage is "worshipping" with two p's, saying that "worshipping" is an exception to a rule about doubling the leading consonant when the preceding vowel is stressed. However, the spell-checker in my browser seems to think that the correct spelling is "worshiping".

This leads me to believe this must be one of those interchangeable British/American things (e.g. "colour/color"). I can't find anything about this on Google, as it just returns a bunch of articles about religion, failing to understand use-mention distinction.

Comment: Related: other questions with the tag [double-consonant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-consonant?sort=votes&pageSize=45), in particular [“Focussed” or “focused”? Rules for doubling the last consonant when adding -ed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-rules-for-doubling-the-last-consonant-when-adding-ed). As far as I know, there are no words where it is standard to use a double consonant before "-ed" but not before "-ing", or vice versa.

Comment: @Sumelic Likewise with *-er* agent nouns like *worshipper*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ngram for 'worshiping/worshipping' [(BrE)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worshiping%2Cworshipping&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworshiping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworshipping%3B%2Cc0) shows a strong favouring of the double 'p'.

The same Ngram for [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worshiping%2Cworshipping&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworshiping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworshipping%3B%2Cc0) shows a 50/50 split.

Therefore, there must be some other influence than just a national preference.

I would suggest that it could be the influence of the Authorised Version where the double 'p' is used throughout :-

> 'Worshipped' - Jeremiah 8:2
>
> 'Worshipping' - Colossians 2:8
>
> 'Worshipper' - John 9:31

Comment: Nice detective work.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just the tyranny of Microsoft Knows Best Syndrome, or some similar force at work, where somebody somewhere has decided how Americans are “supposed” to do things without looking at how they actually do do them, and so via computer programming silently impose their prejudice on the whole world, at which point more and more people figure that the new thing is the "right" thing. There are no "shipes" when *fellowshiped, which is why it's fellowshipped. Same thing for the reset of them. :) Plus programs are too stupidly programmed (not *programed) to accept more than one answer.