# Is travell still an accepted variant of travel?

Tags: orthography

The word travell caught my eye recently.
It seems it's an archaic version of travel.
But is it still in use ?

AmEng traveled/traveling 
BrEng travelled/travelling

But both AmEng and BrEng use travel right ?

https://wikidiff.com/travell/travel

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Focussed" or "focused"? Rules for doubling the last consonant when adding -ed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-rules-for-doubling-the-last-consonant-when-adding-ed) Note that "travel" is spelled with one l, in both Britain and America.

Comment: Is Wikidiff a reliable source? I've never heard of it, nor of _travell_. Dictionaries of current English don't carry _travell_, though it's a very plausible historical spelling variant of _travel_... or perhaps of _travail_. Someone with OED access should be able to help.

Comment: Travell is archaic.  But travelled, traveller, travelling are still used in England.

Comment: @GEdgar perhaps more accurate to say *outside the USA* rather than *in England.*

Answer (score 2):

The OED marks "travell" (both noun and verb) as being "ME–16", which means that it was used in Middle English to the 1600s.  The latest example they have with the spelling is from 1660:

> From Monte Fiascone we travell a plain and pleasant Champion to Viterbo.
>   <sub>[The diary of John Evelyn](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZEArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq="From+Monte+Fiascone+we+travell+a+plain+and+pleasant+Champion+to+Viterbo.")</sub>

I think it's pretty safe to say **no, it is not used anymore**. Everyone spells it "travel".