# Syllables and degrees of comparision

Tags: adjectives, syllables

Rule says:
In a positive degree if a word ends in a **consonant** and there's a **short vowel** before the consonant, then we double the last consonant and add **-er** or **-est**.

**Example:** big -> bigger -> biggest

Why don't we apply this rule to
**Grey**?

Grey -> greyyer -> greyyest

Comment: Why do you think the "e" in *grey* is a short vowel?

Comment: Also, *y* in grey is probably a vowel, not a consonant (since the distinction depends on the sound).

Comment: The doubling rule never applies to the letter **y**. I think my answer to a related question about the doubling rule (before the suffix *-ed*) answers your question also:  ["Focussed" or "focused"? Rules for doubling the last consonant when adding -ed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-rules-for-doubling-the-last-consonant-when-adding-ed)

Comment: @user372766 "*Rule says: In a positive degree if a word ends in a consonant*" - please understand that, in English, there are no "rules"; there is guidance... some guidance looks like a rule, but is probably not.