# "Bias": reason(s) for doubling the last consonant before inflectional endings

Tags: orthography, doubled-consonants

Forms such as *concussed* or *discusses* may lead people to wrongly double the final consonant of *focus* ―at least that's the only reason I have come up with.

Yet, I cannot come up with a potential explanation of why people wrongly write *bia**ss**ed* or the plural *bia**ss**es*, but not *alia**ss**es*

Comment: Personally, I distinguish ***buses*** (public transport vehicles) from ***busses*** (electrical current switching gear). Why that way round and not the other? Do many others make the same (or opposite?) distinction?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Is _transfered_ a misspelling even for the pronunciation with main stress on the first syllable? If so, why is it an exception?

Comment: British usage favors more such consonantal doublings than American does. The usual American practice is to double the final consonant before common terminal inflections  or suffixes only if the root word is accented on the final syllable. This does not apply to *bias,* but some spellers may be motivated to double anyhow for fear lest with only the single *s* that *s* may lose voice (|s| → |z|) and/or the preceding vowel may become long (avoiding spellings like *buses* for fear of their being pronounced as in *he abuses*).

Comment: @BrianDonovan Native speakers do not know about |s| → |z|. What about monosyllabicity, and what visually "seems" a monosyllable (CVVC: _spain_ vs _bias_)

Comment: The verb forms ***transfer, prefer,...*** end in a stressed syllable, which  "explains" why that final **r** is normally doubled in the orthography. But at the end of the day it really is just *orthography*, which is only loosely related to true (spoken) language.

Comment: |s| → |z| is of course *gaining* voice--my bad there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transfer#Etymology for both the verb and the noun; Longman Pronunciation Dictionary for the noun only gives /'trænsfɜr/. Garner's fourth edition: "BrE doubles the final consonant after a fully pronounced vowel in words such as kidnapped, -ing and worshipped, -ing. (One exception is galloped, galloping.)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Focussed" or "focused"? Rules for doubling the last consonant when adding -ed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-rules-for-doubling-the-last-consonant-when-adding-ed)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Unfortunately it doesn't; the only related statement is _"Focussed" **probably** came about because "focused" can be analysed as "fo-cused" or "foc-used",_ which doesn't make any sense at all: there's no English **fo(c)-** or **cuse(d)** either