# What are all the orthographic rules for combining morphemes?

Tags: orthography, morphology

In my computational linguistics class, we talked about the complications with parsing English morphemes, and there was a list of orthographic rules for combining morphemes in the slides.

> - consonant doubling
> - e deletion
> - e insertion
> - y replacement (y -> ies, y -> ied)
> - k insertion (panic -> panicked)

I don't know where this comes from but I found it online in slides for several other universities' computational linguistics classes (e.g. slide 9
of [https://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~fraser/morphology_2016/two_level_morph.pdf](https://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/%7Efraser/morphology_2016/two_level_morph.pdf), slide 8 of https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ee0f/ffc479d6c8b1a2c1ac00f25ce751c27f2150.pdf) . Is this a comprehensive list? And if not, is there are comprehensive one somewhere?, or at least discussion as to why this would be a infeasible?

Comment: Related: "focussed vs. focused" https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-rules-for-doubling-the-last-consonant-when-adding-ed

Comment: No, this is not a comprehensive list.  This is a list of the most common examples.

Comment: There are a lot of irregular words in English (although I guess changes to them aren't rules, the dividing line isn't clear, and some irregular words work quite regularly). You could look at how words ending in "-g" or "-ng" are affected, I'm pretty sure there's are rules there.

Comment: @StuartF What do you mean about words ending in "g" or "ng"?

Comment: I think he means things like *sing* => *sang*.

Comment: Or maybe it's that _singer_ and _finger_ don't rhyme, although their spellings do.

Comment: Section "The alternation rules component" at https://fomafst.github.io/morphtut.html seems to cover what I'm interested in, though it doesn't claim to be comprehensive. Also, I know [Plover](https://github.com/openstenoproject/plover) (machine stenography software) implements orthographic rules for suffixes, but which is essentially what I want, but I don't know if that's comprehensive either. Lastly, the list seems to be sourced from a textbook by Jurafsky & Martin, which is online, so I'll have to take a look there later.

Comment: I always worry when I see someone wants "all" of something.

Answer (score 2):

In British English, there's also u deletion. We have

> clamour, clamorous;
> vigour, invigorate;
> glamour, glamorous;
> odour, deodorant.

(But this u deletion doesn't always happen — we have *honour* and *honourable*.)

So this isn't an exhaustive list.